# Popup with Iframe display JQM

Tags: jquery-mobile, iframe, popup

My popup opens in an anarchic way, it should be opens in the center of the page with an overlay, but it opens another page, by being placed in absolute position with a white background. I want it to open as in the demo jquery

[Popup Iframe](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup-iframe/)

This is an external popup

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popIf" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="a" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content"><iframe src="add.html" width="445" height="225" seamless=""></iframe></div>
        <div data-role="page" id="myfirstpage">
```

JS ==>

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
// The window width and height are decreased by 30 to take the tolerance of 15 pixels at each side into account
function scale( width, height, padding, border ) {
    var scrWidth = $( window ).width() - 30,
        scrHeight = $( window ).height() - 30,
        ifrPadding = 2 * padding,
        ifrBorder = 2 * border,
        ifrWidth = width + ifrPadding + ifrBorder,
        ifrHeight = height + ifrPadding + ifrBorder,
        h, w;
    if ( ifrWidth < scrWidth && ifrHeight < scrHeight ) {
        w = ifrWidth;
        h = ifrHeight;
    } else if ( ( ifrWidth / scrWidth ) > ( ifrHeight / scrHeight ) ) {
        w = scrWidth;
        h = ( scrWidth / ifrWidth ) * ifrHeight;
    } else {
        h = scrHeight;
        w = ( scrHeight / ifrHeight ) * ifrWidth;
    }
    return {
        'width': w - ( ifrPadding + ifrBorder ),
        'height': h - ( ifrPadding + ifrBorder )
    };
};
$( ".ui-popup iframe" )
    .attr( "width", 0 )
    .attr( "height", "auto" );
$( "#popIf" ).on({
    popupbeforeposition: function() {
        // call our custom function scale() to get the width and height
        var size = scale( 445, 225, 15, 1 ),
            w = size.width,
            h = size.height;
        $( "#popIf iframe" )
            .attr( "width", w )
            .attr( "height", h );
    },
    popupafterclose: function() {
        $( "#popIf iframe" )
            .attr( "width", 0 )
            .attr( "height", 0 );
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you initialize the external popup? Add this line at the start of the pagecreate event:

```
$("#popIf").popup().enhanceWithin();
```

Also, how are you launching the popup? make sure you position to window:

```
<a href="#popIf" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline" data-transition="pop" data-position-to="window">Basic Popup</a>
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/vjh29nb6/)**

Comment: Thanks guy, your solves my problem, I also noticed that my button does not have the data-rel = "popup"